# I can no longer use the cd command after I performed usermod -l newname oldname

Tags: bash

Instructions said that usermod -l newname oldname would also change the user home directory /home/oldname. But it looks like that's not the case for me. So I renamed mv /home/oldname newname manually. Now I can't use cd because of the error:
bash: cd: /home/oldname: No such file or directory

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HOME` environment variable of your running shell still has the old name of the directory, same for any other processes you may have running. Logging off and back on again is probably the easiest way to fix that, though you could also manually reset `HOME` to the new path.